# How to send and receive CAN messages between 2 Linux machines without any CAN hardware?

Tags: python, linux, usb, wifi, can-bus

I have been trying to establish CAN communication between my laptop (Ubuntu 20 Virtualbox) and Raspberry Pi (Ubuntu 20) without any CAN hardware, because that will not get the CAN message in the simulation environment. I want to send the CAN data as payload through wifi or USB. Then my python simulation environment should be able to interpret these as CAN messages and forward appropriately.

I have tried `vcan` from `socketcan` but it works only between 2 terminals of the same Linux machine. I have been advised to look at `slcan`. It seems like there is no other option other than using actual CAN hardware. I can't find any tutorial or any other help anywhere.

I will humbly appreciate if anyone can suggest how to send and receive CAN messages between 2 Linux machines without any CAN hardware through wifi or USB?

Python source code I tried:

```
import sys
import socket
import argparse
import struct
import errno


class CANSocket(object):
  FORMAT = "<IB3x8s"
  FD_FORMAT = "<IB3x64s"
  CAN_RAW_FD_FRAMES = 5

  def __init__(self, interface=None):
    self.sock = socket.socket(socket.PF_CAN, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.CAN_RAW)
    if interface is not None:
      self.bind(interface)

  def bind(self, interface):
    self.sock.bind((interface,))
    self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_CAN_RAW, self.CAN_RAW_FD_FRAMES, 1)

  def send(self, cob_id, data, flags=0):
    cob_id = cob_id | flags
    can_pkt = struct.pack(self.FORMAT, cob_id, len(data), data)
    self.sock.send(can_pkt)

  def recv(self, flags=0):
    can_pkt = self.sock.recv(72)

    if len(can_pkt) == 16:
      cob_id, length, data = struct.unpack(self.FORMAT, can_pkt)
    else:
      cob_id, length, data = struct.unpack(self.FD_FORMAT, can_pkt)

    cob_id &= socket.CAN_EFF_MASK
    return (cob_id, data[:length])


def format_data(data):
    return ''.join([hex(byte)[2:] for byte in data])


def generate_bytes(hex_string):
    if len(hex_string) % 2 != 0:
      hex_string = "0" + hex_string

    int_array = []
    for i in range(0, len(hex_string), 2):
        int_array.append(int(hex_string[i:i+2], 16))

    return bytes(int_array)


def send_cmd(args):
    try:
      s = CANSocket(args.interface)
    except OSError as e:
      sys.stderr.write('Could not send on interface {0}\n'.format(args.interface))
      sys.exit(e.errno)

    try:
      cob_id = int(args.cob_id, 16)
    except ValueError:
      sys.stderr.write('Invalid cob-id {0}\n'.format(args.cob_id))
      sys.exit(errno.EINVAL)

    s.send(cob_id, generate_bytes(args.body), socket.CAN_EFF_FLAG if args.extended_id else 0)


def listen_cmd(args):
    try:
      s = CANSocket(args.interface)
    except OSError as e:
      sys.stderr.write('Could not listen on interface {0}\n'.format(args.interface))
      sys.exit(e.errno)

    print('Listening on {0}'.format(args.interface))

    while True:
        cob_id, data = s.recv()
        print('%s %03x#%s' % (args.interface, cob_id, format_data(data)))


def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()

    send_parser = subparsers.add_parser('send', help='send a CAN packet')
    send_parser.add_argument('interface', type=str, help='interface name (e.g. vcan0)')
    send_parser.add_argument('cob_id', type=str, help='hexadecimal COB-ID (e.g. 10a)')
    send_parser.add_argument('body', type=str, nargs='?', default='',
      help='hexadecimal msg body up to 8 bytes long (e.g. 00af0142fe)')
    send_parser.add_argument('-e', '--extended-id', action='store_true', default=False,
      help='use extended (29 bit) COB-ID')
    send_parser.set_defaults(func=send_cmd)

    listen_parser = subparsers.add_parser('listen', help='listen for and print CAN packets')
    listen_parser.add_argument('interface', type=str, help='interface name (e.g. vcan0)')
    listen_parser.set_defaults(func=listen_cmd)

    return parser.parse_args()


def main():
    args = parse_args()
    args.func(args)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Not sure what you want to do. Why not simply opening a TCP-socket between the two machines and send the date? The TCP protocol does not care whether the payload is a CAN message or something else.

Comment: Okay. I am building a virtual platform for specific automotive use cases where the Pi is representing Automotive ECUs. That is why I have to use CAN because ECUs interact with each other through CAN.

Comment: Still not getting it. Yes, ECUs exchange data; yes, in the car they may be using CAN. What are you trying to simulate? The exchanged data? The timing? The CAN protocol is using a well defined physical layer which you cannot simulate without the proper hardware. So what will you be simulating?

Comment: I will simulate the Antilock braking system use case. 1 RPI should send the vehicle speed value to the laptop via CAN.

Comment: But why does it have to be "via CAN". If you want to simulate the braking system, why is it not enough to send the speed value?

Comment: Because the purpose is to simulate the ABS use case similar to how ECUs interact in the car. The goal is to use a socket to communicate packets that have the payload that is the same as a CAN frame.

Comment: „Having the same payload“ is substantially different from „via CAN“. In your (Autosar based) ECU you will also simply get the payload. No matter whether it was received via CAN, Ethernet, LIN, etc. Therefore I still wonder why you try to emulate the exact details of a CAN bus.

Comment: The point is for us to precisely capture communication among ECU while abstracting the ECU implementation. So if we just send the values as payload we can’t do that.  We also can’t optimize for congestion of packets etc.

Comment: @FarhanKabir, take a look at https://github.com/mguentner/cannelloni, which is part of `can-utils`

Comment: @oxuf, I read it. It required at least 1 machine to be connected to a physical CAN Bus

Comment: @FarhanKabir, just change `slcan0` for another `vcan` inteface, it should work

Answer (score 1):

CAN is a *broadcast* protocol and not a connection protocol like TCP or datagram protocol like UDP. However, ff you want abstract the hardware but still simulate the higher layer behaviour of CAN, I'd suggest the best way to do would be with UDP (but TCP as suggested by @M. Spiller also works, just means handling accepting connections which you don't have to bother with for UDP), and send and receive packets with a byte structure the same as a CAN frame. You would also need to account for **filters** and **error frames**.

If you're going to use socketcan on linux, your UDP packets should look like:

```
struct {
    uint16_t id;       /* CAN ID of the frame */
    uint8_t dlc;       /* frame payload length in bytes */
    uint8_t data[8];   /* CAN frame payload */
} simulated_udp_can_frame;
```

You should read the [socketCAN kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/can.txt) for more detail.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I checked the documentation but it does not mention anything about UDP. 
As I am a newbie in this whole thing, just wanted to know: So if I can establish a UDP connection between my laptop and Raspberry Pi, then I can send CAN message without any CAN hardware wirelessly between the laptop and RPI?

Comment: So, without CAN hardware you will miss a lot of the things that you need to do, like set bitrate and so on. But you can 'pretend' that the CAN hardware is there and you are sending **frames** from one end to the other. But actually you will be sending them over UDP. The important thing about frames is setting up filters, message ids and bit ordering, because this is crucial for real CAN software. You can learn that from the socketCAN documentation. You can write your code so these things: filters, frames and ids, are the same as real hardware uses.

Comment: Ok understood. So the concept is that I will be able do to the same thing with socket programming also right? Regardless of whether it is socket or UDP, I will be sending CAN frames. Is it necessary to have the same wifi connection between 2 Linux machines?

Comment: Yes. A CAN socket is like this: socket( PF_CAN, SOCK_RAW, CAN_RAW ); and a UDP socket is  socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP); but they are both sockets. With a CAN socket you read and write; with UDP you send and recv; but the layout of the data can be the same,as mentioned. The 2 linux machines should be on the same subnet if using the same wifi or at least the ip addresses on each machine should be reachable to the other.

Comment: So I can use the CAN socket also or do I need to use the UDP socket only? SocketCAN can work like a UDP socket after binding with any interface. I know I am asking a lot as this is the 1st time I got some answers.
I tried a source code which I just edited in the answer section in both machines but I couldn't receive any CAN message

Comment: if you dont have CAN hardware, you aren't going to get a CAN socket. The socket is created by the kernel and requires a driver and an ip interface which will be called can0 or something, similar to eth0, that kind of interface.

Comment: okay, in that case, I have no option other than using UDP socket right? SocketCAN will not come into the picture then. I should just send messages via UDP pretending it is via CAN

Comment: for the circumstances you've laid out, between two computers with no CAN hardware; yup, totally. Use UDP and pretend. If you could demonstrate on one computer, you could use vcan. If you had some plug in CAN hardware or a CAN emulator, on one PC, then you'd be able to use a CAN socket. But no hardware between two computers ? You have to pretend and UDP is the easiest way to do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your insights. Do you know about any appropriate documentation about how to set up CAN frames to send via UDP socket?

Comment: bro. I'm guessing here but I think you're a newbie to CAN..from an application software point of view (I work in automotive hardware/ software design btw), the thing you have to understand about CAN is that it has a BIT oriented message structure, ie you have to think about the data in terms of bits, not bytes. Start with the Wikipedia article on CAN especially the section about frame layout.